# WinAPI и WaitSingleObject для Mutex

Tags: winapi, windows, многопоточность

Собственно непонятно, каким образом меняется значение, если перед заданием значений используется WaitForSingleObject на dataMutex.

Единственное место, где еще меняется эта переменная, - в main в цикле while, но там используется тоже конструкция WaitForSingleObject на этот же dataMutex.

Весь код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <memory.h>
#define SHAREDMEMORYNAME L"CHATBPSM"
#define INITMUTEXNAME L"INITCBMSHMUTEX"
#define INCPROCMUTEXNAME L"INCPROCMUTEX"
#define INPUTMUTEXNAME L"INPUTCBMSHMUTEX"
#define MSGLEN    1024
#define INFOLEN sizeof(clock_t)+3*sizeof(unsigned char)
#define SHAREDMEMORYSIZE MSGLEN+INFOLEN
// countofproc countofreaded pid clock message'
HANDLE initMutex;
HANDLE incReadCntMutex;
HANDLE inputMutex;
HANDLE dataMutex;
char* shared_data;
char* shared_message;
unsigned char* shared_countOfProcesses;
unsigned char* shared_countOfReadedProc;
unsigned char* shared_messagePID;
clock_t* shared_messageClock;
bool active = true;
unsigned int myID = 0;
char input_buffer[MSGLEN];
void mappingInit(HANDLE sharedMemory){
    shared_data = (char*)MapViewOfFile(sharedMemory,FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0,0,SHAREDMEMORYSIZE);
    shared_countOfProcesses = (unsigned char*)(shared_data);
    shared_countOfReadedProc = (unsigned char*)(shared_data+1);
    shared_messagePID = (unsigned char*)(shared_data+2);
    shared_messageClock = (clock_t*)(shared_data+3);
    shared_message = shared_data+INFOLEN;
}
DWORD WINAPI input_thread_function(LPVOID){
    while(active){
        gets(input_buffer);
        //if(!strcmp(input_buffer,"#quit"))
            //active = false;
        WaitForSingleObject(dataMutex,INFINITE);
        clock_t current_clock = clock();
        memcpy(shared_message,input_buffer,MSGLEN);
        *shared_messagePID = myID;
        *shared_countOfReadedProc = 1;
        *shared_messageClock = current_clock;
        printf("SND: %d %d ]%03d:%s\n",*shared_countOfProcesses,*shared_countOfReadedProc,*shared_messagePID,shared_message);
        ReleaseMutex(dataMutex);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    HANDLE sharedMemory = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,SHAREDMEMORYNAME);
    initMutex = CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,INITMUTEXNAME);
    dataMutex = CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,L"DATAMUdTXCFGSFD");
    //ReleaseMutex(dataMutex);
    WaitForSingleObject(initMutex,INFINITE);
    if(sharedMemory == NULL){
        //инициализируем память
        puts("Init\n");
        sharedMemory = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,0,PAGE_READWRITE,0,SHAREDMEMORYSIZE,SHAREDMEMORYNAME);
        mappingInit(sharedMemory);
        memset(shared_message,0,MSGLEN);
        *shared_countOfProcesses = 1;
        *shared_countOfReadedProc = 1;
        *shared_messageClock = 0;
        *shared_messagePID = 0xFF;
        myID = 1;
    }else{
        puts("Already init\n");
        mappingInit(sharedMemory);
        if(*shared_countOfProcesses<0xff){
            myID = ++*shared_countOfProcesses;
            *shared_countOfReadedProc++;
        }else{
            puts("To many processes!\n");
            ReleaseMutex(initMutex);
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }
    }
    ReleaseMutex(initMutex);
    printf("PID = %d\n",myID);
    clock_t last_printed_message = 0;
    CreateThread(NULL,0,input_thread_function,NULL,0,0);
    while(active){
        WaitForSingleObject(dataMutex,INFINITE);
        if(*shared_messageClock > last_printed_message && *shared_messagePID!=myID){
            printf("%d %d ]%03d:%s\n",*shared_countOfProcesses,*shared_countOfReadedProc,*shared_messagePID,shared_message);
            *shared_countOfReadedProc++;
            last_printed_message = *shared_messageClock;
        }
        ReleaseMutex(dataMutex);
    }
    UnmapViewOfFile(shared_data);
    CloseHandle(sharedMemory);
    CloseHandle(initMutex);
    CloseHandle(dataMutex);
}
```

[image]

Comment: картинка не грузиццо. а вы уверены. что вам нужен WaitForSingleObject для синхронизации? Может быть, вам нужна `[CRITICAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608.aspx)_[SECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684169.aspx)`?

Answer (score 2):

Код, скорее всего, правильный, проблема в `printf`. Глядите: ваш формат содержит `%d %d`. Это значит, что первое *слово* в списке аргументов, лежащем в стеке, интерпретируется как `int` и печатается, так что второй `%d` относится ко второму *слову*, а не ко второму *байту*. Вот.

Попробуйте

```
printf("SND: %d %d ]%03d:%s\n",
       (int)*shared_countOfProcesses,
       (int)*shared_countOfReadedProc,
       (int)*shared_messagePID,
       shared_message);
```